# Converting string which have space in it to numbres

Tags: javascript

I am making a calculator where user can past numbers with spaces like
20 30 40 60 50

and it will calculate all in total = 200

How I can convert this string "20 30 40 60 50" to Numbers with spaces? Because I'll than replace the space with +

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand?

Comment: `"20 30 40 60  50".split(/\s{1,}/).map(Number).reduce((a,v) => a +v)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` with `map` for transform string to number then use `reduce` for sum array like:

```js
const string = '20 30 40 60 50';
const arrayNumbers = string.split(' ').map(el => parseInt(el));
const sum = arrayNumbers.reduce((sumCounter, a) => sumCounter + a, 0);
console.log(arrayNumbers, sum);
```

**Please note:** If you plan to use decimals use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

Reference:

- [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)